# tooltip doesnot dismiss automatically on touch devices

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, tooltip, winrt-xaml

I have created a Windows 8 application using XAML I have used following code to display tooltip on an image:

```
          Text="{Binding MeasureValue, Converter={StaticResource RemoveNegativeDecimalConverter}}" />
                    <Image Source="ms-appx:///DownArrow.png"
                           Width="21"
                           Height="21"
                           ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Value1, Converter={StaticResource RemoveNegativeDecimalConverter}}"
                           Grid.Column="1"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                           Margin="11,0,0,0" />
```

But on touch device tooltipService comes with touch and hold but when i click away or scroll it doesn't goes away or closes as it happens with mouse hover.

How should i fix this? that when i click or scroll away from tooltip it should dismiss??

NOte: Attached new snapshot
[image]

Comment: Hello, Did you find a solution to this?